React Bootstrap Form Validation - isInvalid Not Setting Form Invalid
I have two textboxes on a form, as follows:
<div className="row">
<div className="col-md-6">
    { /* Password */}
    <Form.Group>
        <label>Password</label>
        <Form.Control
            required
            type="password"
            isInvalid={formErrors && formErrors.password}
            onChange={(e) => setField("password", e.target.value)}
            value={form.password ?? ""}
        />
        <Form.Control.Feedback className="text-danger" type="invalid">
            {formErrors.password}
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
</div>
<div className="col-md-6">
    { /* Confirm Password */}
        <Form.Group>
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <Form.Control
                required
                type="password"
                isInvalid={formErrors && formErrors.confirmPassword}
                onChange={(e) => setField("confirmPassword", e.target.value)}
                value={form.confirmPassword ?? ""}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback className="text-danger" type="invalid">
                {formErrors.confirmPassword}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
</div>

On form submit, I then do the following validation:
setFormErrors({
    
    password: form.password == undefined || form.password == "" ? "Password is required" : "",
    confirmPassword: form.confirmPassword == undefined || form.confirmPassword == "" ? "Please confirm the password" : form.password != form.confirmPassword ? "Passwords do not match" : "",
});


if (event.currentTarget.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("Submitting...", form)
}

If the textboxes are left blank, then it works fine, both are highlighted red and the form doesnt submit. However if you enter unmatching passwords, the field is correctly highlighted red indicating the error, however the form still submits.
Why is checkValidity() failing when there is a control marked as invalid on the page?

Instead of manually working out a form validation I strongly recommend to rely on libraries, like Yup for instance.
Take a look at the official React Bootstrap documentation, you'll find great examples to validate your form. There's also plenty of great documentation out there like this article, good luck!
